# Problem with sending iso message using ChannelAdaptor & QMUX

Tags: java, iso8583, jpos

I am using a channel adaptor and qmux to send iso8583 message to a socket server.

I write 2 maven project Jpos client & server in netbeans.

The server accepts the connection but doesnt receive the message (or the client doesnt send message) but when I cancel process of the client project, the server receives

Plz correct me if i wrong.

Following are my configuration files (Refered to http://jpos.org/doc/proguide-draft.pdf)

10_channel.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<channel-adaptor name='test-channel' 
                 class="org.jpos.q2.iso.ChannelAdaptor" logger="Q2">
    <channel class="org.jpos.iso.channel.ASCIIChannel" logger="Q2" realm="test-channel"
                 packager="org.jpos.iso.packager.GenericPackager">       
        <property name="packager-config" value="src/main/resources/iso8583.xml" />
        <property name="host" value="127.0.0.1" />
        <property name="port" value="9090" />
        <property name="connection-timeout" value="15000" /> 
        <property name="timeout" value="3000000" />
        <property name="keep-alive" value="true" />  
    </channel>
<!--    <ignore-iso-exceptions>yes</ignore-iso-exceptions>-->
    <in>client-send</in>
    <out>client-receive</out>
    <reconnect-delay>10000</reconnect-delay>
</channel-adaptor>
```

20_mux.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mux class="org.jpos.q2.iso.QMUX" logger="Q2" name="test-mux">
    <in>client-receive</in>
    <out>client-send</out>
    <ready>test-channel.ready</ready>
    <unhandled>myunhandledqueue</unhandled>
    <key>2 7</key> 
</mux>
```

JPos Client code

```
Q2 q2 = new Q2("src/main/deploy/");
q2.start();
QMUX mux = (QMUX)NameRegistrar.getIfExists("mux.test-mux");
if (mux != null && mux.isConnected()) {
            ISOMsg request = new IsoMessage().build();    //dump iso message
            ISOMsg response = mux.request(request, REQUEST_TIMEOUT);
            if (response != null) {
                ISOMsg receivedIsoMsg = new ISOMsg();
                receivedIsoMsg.setPackager(new GenericPackager("path_to_file_xml"));
                receivedIsoMsg.unpack(response.getBytes());
                receivedIsoMsg.dump(System.out, "");
            }
  }
```

Socket Server Code

```
ServerSocket serverSocket;
try {
            System.out.println("Binding to port " + SERVER_PORT + ", please wait  ...");
            serverSocket = new ServerSocket(SERVER_PORT);
            System.out.println("Server started: " + serverSocket);
            System.out.println("Waiting for a client ...");
            while (true) {
                try {
                    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
                    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
                    String message = (String) dis.readLine();
                    System.out.println("Message Received: " + message);                   
                    ISOMsg receivedIsoMsg = new ISOMsg();
                    receivedIsoMsg.setPackager(new GenericPackager("path_to_file_xml"));
                    receivedIsoMsg.unpack(message.getBytes());
                    receivedIsoMsg.setMTI("0110");
                    receivedIsoMsg.set(39,"00");
                    receivedIsoMsg.dump(System.out, "");
                    DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
                    //write object to Socket
                    dos.writeUTF(new String(receivedIsoMsg.pack()));

                } catch (IOException | ISOException ex) {
                    System.err.println(ex);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            try {
                serverSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                 System.err.println(ex);
            }
        }
```

Trace log
Client:

```
--- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) @ JposTest ---
<log realm="Q2.system" at="2020-07-30T10:45:25.638">
  <info>
    Q2 started, deployDir=/Users/lap/NetBeansProjects/JposTest/src/main/deploy, environment=default
  </info>
</log>
<log realm="Q2.system" at="2020-07-30T10:45:26.160" lifespan="507ms">
  <version>
    jPOS 2.1.3 master/95b8dce (2019-06-16 15:16:57 ART) 

-----BEGIN PGP SIGNED MESSAGE-----
Hash: SHA1

jPOS Community Edition, licensed under GNU AGPL v3.0.
This software is probably not suitable for commercial use.
Please see http://jpos.org/license for details.

-----BEGIN PGP SIGNATURE-----
Version: GnuPG v1.4.9 (Darwin)

iQEcBAEBAgAGBQJMolHDAAoJEOQyeO71nYtFv74H/3OgehDGEy1VXp2U3/GcAobg
HH2eZjPUz53r38ARPiU3pzm9LwDa3WZgJJaa/b9VrJwKvbPwe9+0kY3gScDE1skT
ladHt+KHHmGQArEutkzHlpZa73RbroFEIa1qmN6MaDEHGoxZqDh0Sv2cpvOaVYGO
St8ZaddLBPC17bSjAPWo9sWbvL7FgPFOHhnPmbeux8SLtnfWxXWsgo5hLBanKmO1
1z+I/w/6DL6ZYZU6bAJUk+eyVVImJqw0x3IEElI07Nh9MC6BA4iJ77ejobj8HI2r
q9ulRPEqH9NR79619lNKVUkE206dVlXo7xHmJS1QZy5v/GT66xBxyDVfTduPFXk=
=oP+v
-----END PGP SIGNATURE-----

  </version>
</log>
<log realm="Q2.system" at="2020-07-30T10:45:26.168" lifespan="5ms">
  <info>
    deploy: /Users/lap/NetBeansProjects/JposTest/src/main/deploy/10_zp_channel.xml
  </info>
</log>
<log realm="Q2.system" at="2020-07-30T10:45:26.199" lifespan="30ms">
  <info>
    deploy: /Users/lap/NetBeansProjects/JposTest/src/main/deploy/20_zp_qmux.xml
  </info>
</log>
<log realm="Q2.system" at="2020-07-30T10:45:26.207" lifespan="8ms">
  <info>
    deploy: /Users/lap/NetBeansProjects/JposTest/src/main/deploy/99_sysmon.xml
  </info>
</log>
<log realm="org.jpos.q2.qbean.SystemMonitor" at="2020-07-30T10:45:26.225">
  <info>
    Starting SystemMonitor
  </info>
</log>
<log realm="org.jpos.q2.qbean.SystemMonitor" at="2020-07-30T10:45:26.225">
  <info>
               ......
     thread count: 10
     peak threads: 10
     user threads: 7
            Thread[Reference Handler,10,system]
            Thread[Finalizer,8,system]
            Thread[Signal Dispatcher,9,system]
            Thread[main,5,main]
            Thread[pool-1-thread-1,5,main]
            Thread[Q2-dd666708-34a1-46dc-9a10-4df253d9249a,5,main]
            Thread[Thread-1,5,main]
            Thread[channel-sender-client-send,5,main]
            Thread[channel-receiver-client-receive,5,main]
            Thread[SystemMonitor,5,main]
    name-registrar:
      tspace:default: org.jpos.space.TSpace
         key-count: 0
            gcinfo: 0,0
      Q2: org.jpos.q2.Q2
      test-channel: org.jpos.q2.iso.ChannelAdaptor
        tx=0, rx=0, connects=0, last=0
      logger.Q2: org.jpos.util.Logger
      channel.test-channel: org.jpos.iso.channel.ASCIIChannel
      mux.test-mux: org.jpos.q2.iso.QMUX
        tx=0, rx=0, tx_expired=0, tx_pending=0, rx_expired=0, rx_pending=0, rx_unhandled=0, rx_forwarded=0, connected=false, last=0
      logger.: org.jpos.util.Logger
  </info>
</log>
<log realm="test-channel/127.0.0.1:9090" at="2020-07-30T10:45:36.309" lifespan="10084ms">
  <connect>
    Try 0 127.0.0.1:9090
  </connect>
</log>

<log realm="test-channel/127.0.0.1:9090" at="2020-07-30T10:45:55.579" lifespan="1ms">
  <send>
    <isomsg direction="outgoing">
      <!-- org.jpos.iso.packager.GenericPackager[src/main/resources/iso8583.xml] -->
      <field id="0" value="0100"/>
      <field id="2" value="123456"/>
      <field id="3" value="000010"/>
      <field id="4" value="1500"/>
      <field id="7" value="1206041200"/>
      <field id="11" value="000001"/>
      <field id="41" value="12340001"/>
      <field id="49" value="840"/>
    </isomsg>
  </send>
</log>
```

Server:

```
--- exec-maven-plugin:1.2.1:exec (default-cli) @ AppTest ---
Binding to port 9090, please wait  ...
Server started: ServerSocket[addr=0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0,localport=9090]
Waiting for a client ...
Client accepted: Socket[addr=/127.0.0.1,port=58902,localport=9090]
```

=> the Client cannot send message
But if I cancel process of client project, the Server receives message & print log:

```
Message Received: 00730100722000000080800006123456000010000000001500120604120000000112340001840
<isomsg>
  <!-- org.jpos.iso.packager.GenericPackager -->
  <field id="0" value="0110"/>
  <field id="8" value="80000612"/>
  <field id="18" value="3456"/>
  <field id="19" value="000"/>
  <field id="20" value="010"/>
  <field id="23" value="000"/>
  <field id="27" value="0"/>
  <field id="39" value="00"/>
  <field id="57" value=""/>
</isomsg>
```

Answer (score 2):

Problem is you are trying to receive the message using `readLine`  and iso messages are not strings ended with an EOL.

I believe what's happening is that when the client disconnects the `readLine` method returns, because the input stream is closed.

It would be better to use `ISOServer` on your server, or even better a full `q2` to implement it.

Otherwise you should first read the message length and then read that amount of bytes from the input stream, instead of waiting for a new line character that may or may not be part of the message itself

You can follow the first two jpos tutorials here http://www.jpos.org/tutorials, to get an idea on how to configure a Server with a request listener to process requests.

Comment: Thank you. I've tried following your suggestion and it has worked. :D